# Is there a straightforward way to have a jQuery animation on a collection create a new promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, promise

When I call the `promise` method on a jQuery collection without any arguments I get a promise that resolves once all animations on the element in the collection are finished. Every further call to the same method on that element will just return the same promise. Is there a straightforward way to "reset" the promise so that once the initial animation is complete and the initial promise has resolved, I can handle when the next animation is completed?

```
$('.some-element').slideDown();
$('.some-element').promise().done(function () {
  // e.g. evaluate the "display" property of the element which should not be "none"
  this.slideUp();
  this.promise().done(function () {
    // e.g. evaluate the "display" property of the element which should be "none"
  });
});
```

The problem in the code above is that the second call to `promise` returns the same promise as the first call. Since that promise has already been resolved, the evaluation in the second handler shows the "display" property is not "none" since the `slideUp` animation is not yet finished.

Comment: Are you sure `this` refers to the jQuery object? It seems to me `this.slideUp()` and `this.promise()` should not work at all. If you call `.promise` on a new jQuery object, it surely will return a new promise.

Comment: Why not just call `.then(function() { /* whatever */ })` on the original promise object?

Comment: @FelixKling According to one example on the documentation page for the <code>promise</code> method the value of this is equivalent to the collection from which you call the <code>promise</code> method. I haven't had any issues with the value of this in this context.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me -> **http://jsfiddle.net/fgnXp/1/**

Comment: @Pointy That has the same effect as what my example code which is that a promise can only be resolved once. I want to do something upon completion of the animation initiated by jQuery when I call the <code> slideUp</code> method. Ideally, I would have an event I could listen to instead of having to rely on promises since promises are meant for singular asynchronous tasks.

Comment: Thanks @adeneo. I'm seeing different behavior in my environment so I guess for now my next step is to see whether there's an issue with the jQuery version I'm using or something about my environment that's impacting the behavior. Thanks again!

Comment: I provided a poor example as my actual code initiated the animations based on click events on a particular element. Nonetheless, I see where I went wrong. As @adeneo pointed out, the method works as intended. The problem I had stemmed from calling the <code>promise</code> method too early. http://jsfiddle.net/fgnXp/2/ I had a call <code>$('.content').promise().done</code> at the root context but keeping those calls within the event handlers works fine as evidenced by my updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function () {
    function slider(d, next, callback) {
        $("div").slideUp({
            duration: d,
            done: function (promise) {
                if (promise.state() === "resolved" 
                   && $(this).css("display") === "none") {
                    console.log($(this).css("display"));
                    $(this).slideDown({
                        duration: d,
                        done: function (promise) {
                            if (promise.state() === "resolved" 
                               && $(this).css("display") === "block") {
                                console.log($(this).css("display"));
                                slider(next, (d + next) / 2, function () {
                                    console.log("next animation beginning at " 
                                               + $.now());
                                });
                            }
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                            return callback != undefined ? callback() : $.noop();
                        }
                    });
                };
            }
        });
    };
    slider(3000, 1500, function () {
        console.log("next animation beginning at " + $.now())
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/3xdmD/

See http://api.jquery.com/slideup/ , http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/ `options` at `start`, `progress` , `done`, `always` (`promises`) ; see also `step` , `complete` callbacks

Answer (score -1):

You can pass an array of promises to `$.when`, as reported in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Comment: Please expand this to an answer.

Comment: @ArtoAle I believe the <code>$.when</code> method is similar to the native <code>Promise.all</code> method where the goal is to do something once multiple promises have all been resolved (you don't want to react until you know that a bunch of asynchronous tasks have all completed). What I'm trying to do is handle when an animation completes on a specific element and then handle differently the next time an animation completes on the same exact element. An event listener to observe animation completion would be preferable here...